# SQL error in CASE expression

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    AM.programid,
    AM.ProjectNumber,
    AM.AppID,
    AM.DateCreated,
    CASE WHEN AM.applicationentryflag = 210
              AND YEAR(App646.Application_Received_Date) = CONVERT(INT,@PY)
         THEN CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),App646.Application_Received_Date,101) AS DATETIME)
         WHEN AM.applicationentryflag <> 210
              AND YEAR(AM.datecreated) = CONVERT(INT,@PY)
         THEN CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),AM.datecreated,101) AS DATETIME) 
     END AS [Date_App_Rec]
```

I get the following error when executing this code:

> At least one of the result expressions in a `CASE` specification must be
>   an expression other than the `NULL` constant.

Comment: As @jarlh likes to say, it's a `CASE` _expression_, not specification :-)

Comment: Cannot infer datatype eg:
SELECT CASE WHEN 1 = 2 THEN NULL ELSE NULL END

Comment: why are you converting a `DATE` or `DATETIME` to `VARCHAR(10)` and then back to `DATETIME`?

Comment: When neither case condition is hit, what would the datatype for the column be? Undefined right?  so the case itself needs to be cast to a datetime. or you need an "else" to cast Null to datetime.

Comment: The error message you are receiving doesn't seem related to the code you have shown.

Comment: what is AM? can you post your complete query?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Corrected. Thank you!

Comment: @Lamak It is default thing we follow at my work as many of the columns that are created, are created as VARCHAR including the date types.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when SQL can't infer a type, which means that all results in one of your `case` expressions are `null` for example:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 1 = 0 THEN NULL ELSE NULL END
```

I tested your Case statement with a static `date` and it doesn't seem to have a problem. (However, I am not sure why you would convert `date` to `varchar(10)` then back to `DATETIME`)

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),'2017-08-31',101) AS DATETIME)
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),'2017-08-31',101) AS DATETIME)
```

so I doubt the error is from the code you have shown us.

Comment: It is default thing we follow at my work as many of the columns that are created, are created as VARCHAR even if it is a date or a string.Like you mentioned, SQL wasn't able to infer the datatype and was taking it as NULL. Now the query works. Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean by created as varchar including the date types? a column is either a varchar or date types. it cannot be both